# Array to string conversion in Vigenere

Tags: php, vigenere

Can somebody help me, tells me where it went wrong, because the code below return "Array to string conversion".

```
$bigarray = [range('a','z')];
    for( $i=1; $i<=26; $i++) {
        $copy = $bigarray[$i-1]; 
        array_push($copy,array_shift($copy));
        $bigarray[$i] = $copy;
        echo "<td>$bigarray[$i]</td>";
    }
```

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Learnphp\Test 1.php on line 15

Comment: Usually the error would show you which line the error is on, this is a big help in fixing most problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
range('a','z') // returns [a,b,c,d,e, etc]
```

you are placing one array in another array.